# How do I add a custom web control to a ViewModel in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view in an MVC app that uses a viewmodel.
 All of the controls on the view are linked to the viewmodel (i.e. `@html.textboxfor(model => model.ViewModel.Class)`) except for one - a select control that I created as a cascading ddl that changes based on the value of the `DropDownListFor` above it.

How can I include the selected value from this custom select in the viewmodel and pass it back to the controller as part of the `FormMethod.Post`?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind it as an action parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(YuorModel model, string fieldname)
```

or you can retrieve it from a `FormCollection`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourAction(YuorModel model, FormCollection form)
{
    var param = form["fieldname"];
}
```

or just add this field to the viewmodel using the field name of the control.

Comment: Why killing the whole benefit of using view models by introducing this FormCollection?

Comment: I've added string fieldname to the controller, and set the name= attribute of my select control to the same value. It does get populated in the controller but to 0 which is the index number of the select value. Any idea how I can get the text instead of the index value?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the view model is exactly for that. You add to it whatever properties you need in the view. In this case you seem to be talking about some DropDown. In order to have a dropdown you need 2 properties: a scalar property to hold the selected value and an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to hold the possible values.

So go ahead and add those 2 properties to your view model:

```
public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values { get; set; }
```

and then your controller action that is serving the view should populate the Values collection property with all available values and then bind the dropdown in the view to those 2 properties:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Values)
```

and of course since your POST action is taking the view model as argument you can simply look at the `model.SelectedValue` property in order to retrieve the value that was selected by the user.